# Java: Unable to Pass Arguments to Constructor

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass a Boolean value to constructor from 1 class to another.

Basically my program begins in Main as follows:

```
    boolean  bbb = true;
    System.out.println("Value of bbb " + bbb);
    signup s = new signup(bbb);
    s.signupnow(driver);
```

The value of "bbb" is set to true.

The "signup" looks like this ( I'm passing value of "bbb" as argument to next constructor)

```
public class Signup {
    boolean isStealthEnabled;
    public Signup(boolean b)
    {
        this.isStealthEnabled = b;
        System.out.println("Value of b inside \"Signup\" " + b);
    }

    Reg signup = new Reg(isStealthEnabled);
```

I'm passing Boolean value to "Reg" class.

However for some reason the value is shown (and executed as false)..

The "Reg" class looks like this:

```
boolean isStealthEnabled;
public Reg(boolean isStealthEnabled) {
    super(isStealthEnabled);
    System.out.println("Value of isStealthEnabled inside of Reg " + isStealthEnabled);
}
StealthWatchDog watchdog = new StealthWatchDog(isStealthEnabled);
```

"GReg" inherits "Reg" class.

public class GmailRegistration extends Registration{

```
//boolean isStealthEnabled;
public GReg(boolean isStealthEnabled) {
    super(isStealthEnabled);
    System.out.println("Value of isStealthEnabled inside of GReg " + isStealthEnabled);
}
StealthWatchDog watchdog = new StealthWatchDog(isStealthEnabled);
```

Initially the value shows up as true but then for some odd reason turns to false.. Why is this?

UPDATE:

In my tests when I try echoing value of isStealthEnabled (or bbb) I get the following:

```
Value of bbb true
Value of b inside StealthWatchDog false
Value of isStealthEnabled inside Reg  false
Value of b inside StealthWatchDog false
Value of isStealthEnabled inside of GReg false
Value of b inside "Signup" true
```

Apparently signup is running last even though I call it first in "Main".

Comment: Where do you call the `new Reg(isStealthEnabled);`? You likely should declare your `Reg signup` field in the class but call the constructor inside the Signup constructor.

Comment: set `isStealthEnabled` as final and try again.

Comment: Post short but complete code which will let us reproduce your problem. For now I see two possible problems (1) having two `isStealthEnabled` variables - in super and subclass (2) `StealthWatchDog watchdog = new StealthWatchDog(isStealthEnabled);` is executed right after `super(isStealthEnabled);` but is using `isStealthEnabled` declared in `Reg`, not in `Signup` (assuming that this is superclass of `Reg`).

Comment: I heartily second @Pshemo's recommendation. Your creating and posting a simple [mcve] would likely clarify the issue fully for us. Of course no one can or should force you to do this, but in my experience, the effort is well worth it and often reduces a great deal of frustration on your part and on our part.

Comment: Hang on guys with the down votes I'm updating the OP

Comment: Don't get discouraged by down-votes. They can be removed if you improve your question and provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also don't worry if your question will be closed before you provide SSCCE, since questions can be also reopened.

Comment: Thanks.. I updated post with more code and output of program I think it can be ran stand alone if not let me know I will add more.. Don't want to overburden people with irrelevant code..

Comment: Point of SSCCE is to make possibly shortest but **complete** code which we could simply copy-paste to your editors to reproduce your issue. Don't leave any information unclear like which class extends which, which methods you used, and when. So take your time, and create example like `class Foo{...}` `class Bar extends Foo{...}` `class Main{psv main(){testing code})`. The more effort you put into creating easy example, the more people will get discouraged by having to think how to use your code to get same problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boolean defaults to false - its building the Reg object before the constructor is even run.

Move the construction of Reg to inside of the constructor.

```
public class Signup {
  boolean isStealthEnabled;
  Reg signup;
  public Signup(boolean b)
  {
    this.isStealthEnabled = b;
    this.signup = new Reg(isStealthEnabled);
    System.out.println("Value of b inside \"Signup\" " + b);
  }
}
```

Comment: your answe is correct ( I will accept it) but I'm trying to understand why the value is passed correctly when I declare it outside the constructor..? Any reference or explanation would be good..

Comment: @JamesSmith We can't give you 100% correct explanation without seeing your actual code, and guessing in most cases in waste of time. So until you update your question you will see only guesses.

Comment: How I explained you before the problem is that you initialize Reg using iStealthEnabled before it has been initialized. So it is set to false for java policy. False is the default value for a not initialized boolean.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

First:

You have to initialize your class with the correct name.
You have defined your class as "Signup" but you have initialized:

```
signup s = new signup(bbb);
```

The problem is that it should be instead:

```
Signup s = new Signup(bbb);
```

Second:

You have declared your Reg element outside any method. It will be initialized with:

```
boolean iStealthEnabled = false;
```

that is the default value for a boolean. It won't be the one you have choosen because at the moment of initialization it hasn't been assigned.

You have to initialize the Reg class inside your Signup constructor and then it will work.

The correct code will be

Main class:

```
boolean  bbb = true;
System.out.println("Value of bbb " + bbb);
Signup s = new Signup(bbb);
s.signupnow(driver);
```

Signup declaration will be:

```
public class Signup {
boolean isStealthEnabled;
Reg signup;
public Signup(boolean b)
{
    this.isStealthEnabled = b;
    System.out.println("Value of b inside \"Signup\" " + b);
    signup = new Reg(isStealthEnabled);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare member variable `boolean isStealthEnabled;` in child class. It may shadow the parent class member that you are setting in parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your main code should be

```
boolean  bbb = true;
System.out.println("Value of bbb " + bbb);
Signup s = new Signup(bbb); // Changed first letter to capital
s.signupnow(driver);
```

This is because classes should be in CamelCase in Java.
See [the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from @Michael Watson I was able I solve the problem as follows:

I changed two classes

```
public class Reg {
boolean isStealthEnabled;
StealthWatchDog watchdog;
public Reg(boolean isStealthEnabled)
{
    this.isStealthEnabled = isStealthEnabled;
    watchdog =   watchdog = new StealthWatchDog(isStealthEnabled);
    System.out.println("Value of isStealthEnabled inside Reg  " + isStealthEnabled);
}



public class Signup {
boolean isStealthEnabled;
GReg signup;
public Signup(boolean b)
{
    this.isStealthEnabled = b;
    System.out.println("Value of b inside \"Signup\" " + b);
    signup = new GReg(isStealthEnabled);

}
```

I am giving credit to @Watson however I'm adding this myself because it did not fix both class's (although concept is the same)

Comment: Why do you need `isStealthEnabled` in `Signup` if you already it in `Reg`? How exactly you want to use these variable?